# Ion-button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, button, ionic-framework

I want to use special buttons for ionic 1, using ion-button, explained in this page: [Ionic Buttons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/button/Button/)
thus, I tryed two buttons, a Round Button and an Outline + Round:

```
  <h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;">Oggetto {{ selectedproduct.idproduct }} <img src="img/cart.png" height="30" width="38"></h2>   

  <ul class = "licatalog">

    <li>
        <h4 style = "color:#4e67c3;"> {{ selectedproduct.productDesc.description }} </h4>
        <h4 style = "color:#FF2E24;"> {{ selectedproduct.productDesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
        <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
        <h4> € {{ selectedproduct.productDesc.price }} </h4>
        <img src="../img/product/{{ selectedproduct.productDesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
    </li>     


  </ul>
    <button ion-button round>Round Button</button>
    <button ion-button round outline>Outline + Round</button>
```

But the button are not working good, they stay like simple buttons:[image: View]

But I don't know the reason why. Somebody can help me to make a finest button?

Comment: actually not, I use this <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using ionic v1. First of all i would recommend you to use later versions of ionic because there are more useful tutorials and less bugs.

If you stay at v1 you need to take the right documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components/#buttons

You use buttons like this: (with the class="")

```html
<button class="button button-positive">
  button-positive
</button>

<button class="button button-outline button-positive">
  Outlined Button
</button>
```

Comment: Yes, I use Ionic v1, and this your solution works fine